# Do Vaishnavas believe in JivanaMukti?

Tags: advaita, vaishnavism, gaudiya-vaishnavism

I want to know if the concept of JivanMukta(attaining moksha while in this very body) exist in Vaishnava sects? From what I know through ISKCON/Gaudiya Vaishnava, Advaita Moksha/Mukti means merging with God(Krishna)'s BrahmaJyoti (effulgence). I don't know if there are other definitions of Moksha in Vaishnavism.

So I want to know if one can be self realized while in this very body according to Vaishnava sects.

Comment: Self realized need not be muktha and the definition of realization is different for different philosophy

Comment: Jivanmukti seems to be exclusive to Advaita , in the light of Upanishads. Vaishnava sects are aligned to Kramamukti , liberation by stages, they go to brahmaloka, goloka , vaikuntha, and from there they may attain liberation.